# Stuck in VT3 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ssh, tty

When my system froze, I used Ctrl + Alt + F3 to enter Virtual terminal. Then I logged in and shutdown my system. Now when the system boots, it opens into a black screen (no text). I guess it is stuck in that VT. I am able to connect to this system via ssh from other system. How to exit from VT ? Tried Ctrl + alt + F7/F8 etc..

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 18, do you mean Ubuntu Core 18 (a IoT appliance intended release? or a standard *yy.mm* format release?). I suspect the ctrl+alt+f3 is not your issue; only significant because that's clear in your memory. As you can login via terminal, I'd explore your `history` to see if it can jog your memory as to anything that was changed in the last session, OR start diagnostics on hardware (esp. video assuming it's not a headless Ubuntu Core 18 install).

Comment: First of all, it seems that your system freezes a lot. Why a super stable Linux should freeze at all? If I were you I would investigate that first... Perhaps your video drivers are buggy? Do you have an NVidia video card? Did you try to install the NVidia proprietary drivers?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The system doesn't freeze often. Maybe once in month. Nvidia drivers are installed in the system